# Type Any don't have member count, two dimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

hi I want to make a view like this picture below, so what I try to do is to make a two dimensional array with UITableViewCell and a string. Since it types Any the compiler complain "Type Any don't have a member of count and subscript". is it my approach right? to make this view like the picture below, or should I create one by one?

[image: tableViewGroup]

This is my code

```
var tableItems = [
        [ProgressCell.self],
        ["Information", "Address", "Password"],
        ["Help", "Term and Condition", "Privacy"],
        [SignOutCell]
    ] as Any

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableItems[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)

    let name                = tableItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! Int

    cell.textLabel?.text    = name
    cell.textLabel?.font    = UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-Regular", size: 16)
    cell.accessoryType      = .disclosureIndicator

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to define an array that contains `Any` item, which would look like this `[[Any]]`

Update your code to the following:

```
var tableItems = [
    [ProgressCell.self],
    ["Information", "Address", "Password"],
    ["Help", "Term and Condition", "Privacy"],
    [SignOutCell]
] as [[Any]]
```

As suggested by @fogmeister in the comment below you shouldn't be really be using `Any` and that further work needs to be done to define the types correctly.

Comment: You could even use `[[Any]]` as it is a two dimensional array. I would suggest though, that you shouldn't be using `Any` at all and that further work needs to be done with the data model.

Comment: true @Fogmeister,  just trying to get the OP up and running

Comment: Definitely :-) baby steps first.  Just adding the comment as a possible suggestion.

Comment: hey thank you @PaulFitzgerald your code is work, like you suggest I think I need to change how I structure the tableView section cell. thank you for you help both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me. Moreover, `self` was also needed for SignOutCell. Please see the attached link as well.

```
var tableItems = [
    [ProgressCell.self],
    ["Information", "Address", "Password"],
    ["Help", "Term and Condition", "Privacy"],
    [SignOutCell.self] as [Any]
  ]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QexjG.png